# Prove or disprove: $ \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q[i]}$ is integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $ \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q[i]}$ an integral domain ?

My attempt :  I know that  $ \mathbb{Q} \times   \mathbb{Q}$  is not integral domain take  $(0,1) \times (1,0) =( 0,0)$

But im confused in $ \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q[i]}$

Comment: This is low effort, how long have you thought about this?

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg I mean, it's not _very_ high effort, but they have shown some individual work here. More than many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same example works.  Here's another $(0, i) \times (1, 0) = (0, 0)$.

Answer (score 2):

You may use same argument to show $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}[i]$ is not an integral domain as $(q,0)\times (0,q')=(0,0),$ for any two non zero rational number $q,q'.$

Infact if $R$ and $R'$ are fields even, $R\times R'$ can never become integral domain.